# Redirect Web Subfolder to Root (/folder to /)

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, mod-rewrite, .htaccess

I am trying to redirect /folder to / using .htaccess but all am I getting is the Apache HTTP Server Test Page.
My root directory looks like this:

```
/
.htaccess
-/folder
-/folder2
-/folder3
```

My .htaccess looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder/
RewriteRule (.*) /folder/$1
```

What am I doing wrong? I checked my httpd.conf (I'm running Centos) and the mod_rewrite library is being loaded. As a side note, my server is not a www server, it's simply a virtual machine so it's hostname is centosvm.

Addition: My httpd.conf looks like so:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName taa.local
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "dev"
        Alias /taa /var/www/html/taa/public
        <Directory /var/www/html/taa/public>
                DirectoryIndex index.php
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that my `<VirtualHost>` declaration was missing a `<Directory>` declaration for root. By changing my `<VirtualHost` to:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName taa.local
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "dev"
        Alias /folder1 /var/www/html/folder1/public
        <Directory /var/www/html>
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/html/folder1/public>
                DirectoryIndex index.php
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

My /.htaccess looks like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder1/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder2/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder3/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder4/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder5/
RewriteRule (.*) folder1/$1 [L]
```

It would be cleaner if I knew hot to say if `REQUEST_URI = /`, then redirect but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure Mod_Rewrite is loaded. Make sure you have `AllowOverrides All` on your root directory (it's the Apache default, but most distros have a default `none` in the httpd.conf file).

Comment: I do have allow Overrides All turned on.

Answer (score 0):

You need to drop the initial '/' from a match with RewriteCond

See the examples in http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^folder/ 
RewriteRule (.*) /folder/$1
```